# Error inflating AppWidget

Tags: android, widget, android-appwidget, inflate

I am doing a simple widget for the first time and it seems the tutorial I'm using has something missing because my LogCat states "Error inflating AppWidget" when selecting it from the pop up list of widgets.

According to the tutorial I did these.

Layout:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/widget_textview" android:text="@string/widget_text"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:padding="10dip"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Class:

```
package hello.widget;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;

public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
}
```

Strings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Hello Widget</string>
    <string name="widget_text">Hello Widget!</string>
</resources>
```

Widget Provider:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    android:minWidth="146dip"
    android:minHeight="72dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="10000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/main"
</appwidget-provider>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="hello.widget" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <!-- Broadcast Receiver that will process AppWidget updates -->
    <receiver android:name="hello.widget.HelloWidget" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/hello_widget_provider" />
    </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the opening `<LinearLayout>` in your layout file. What you have here should not even compile.

You are also missing the entire implementation of your `AppWidgetProvider`. You need to implement `onUpdate()` to specify what the app widget should be displaying.

Also, your `updatePeriodMillis` is shorter than allowed -- you cannot update an app widget every 10 seconds this way.

Also, make sure that your layout is named `main.xml`, or update your `android:initialLayout` to reflect the proper name of the layout.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. It's up and running now.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals(action))
    {   
        long days = (((calendar.getTimeInMillis()- date1.getTime())/1000))/86400;
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

        //Intent AlarmClockIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER).setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.alarmclock", "com.android.alarmclock.AlarmClock"));
        // PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, AlarmClockIntent, 0);
        Intent Date_Change= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent2=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, Date_Change, 0);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.textView1, pendingIntent2);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1,""+days);

        //views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.AnalogClock, pendingIntent);

        //AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS), views);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, views);
    }
}
```